# Making (theoreticly) infinite dictionaries in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I recently looked up this topic but dint find a satisfying answer. Everybody said using dictionaries is the best way , but I don’t know how to apply that in this case:

I want a function that generates me a list of objects generated by a class.
So in pseudo-code something like :

```
for a in range(100):
    tmp = "object" + str(a)
    var(tmp) = someclass()
    list add tmp
```

**Edit** , because of being marked as an duplicate.

I don’t want an answer how dictionary work , I know that. I want to know , how I can make entries which consists of an entry-name and the generated objects for that name.
I need a dictionary which looks something like:
{"1" : obj1 , "2" : obj2, "3" : obj3 ... }

**Edit two:**
I ended up using a list instead of a dictionary which is massively easier:

```
    for tmp in range(100):
        tmpobj = objclass()
        list.append(tmpobj)
```

thanks for help ;)

Comment: This has nothing to do with generators. And yes, you should use a dict or a list, as recommended in all the other answers about this exact question.

Comment: Comprehensive guide to generators is available [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python)

Comment: Thanks for the guide in generators ;)

Comment: But how i use a dictionary in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary comprehension :

```
{ var("object" + str(a)) : someclass() for a in range(100) }
```

Comment: I know the problem here is the var() function , which doesn’t exists. But still thanks for helping ;)

Comment: @MaxLange you're welcome ! if you found this answer helpful you can tell this to community with vote  or accept !